# Are there holiday villages for large families in the Italian Lakes region?

Tags: italy, group-travel

Next year we'd like to go on holiday with two families (total 4 adults, 5 small children) to the Italian Lakes region. Unfortunately, all my web searches turn up bungalows of maximum 7 people in holiday villages such as Continental Lido. We really prefer the two families to reside in a single bungalow. Are there any holiday villages in that region where this is possible?

The reason for a holiday village and not a house on the countryside, is that there's usually a lot more entertainment for the kids in a village, thus more rest for the adults. :-)

Comment: The norm at Holiday villages in that situation I think is to ask for 2 adjacent houses.

Comment: As the maximum usually reflects the number of beds, you may be okay in a 7-person bungalow if some of the little ones are small enough to share.

Answer (score 4):

Side note: I love when things like that just pop out and you discover "definitions" no one person you know in that area would ever use, like when Milano inhabitants discovered that GMaps decided that there is a Chinatown in the city :-D

Anyway, bttq: the concept of "Italian lake region" cover a surface of about 11.000 km, so maybe you should narrow things a bit. If, however, you are just searching for a camping on a lake in that area, with kids, your best bet is Garda Lake, for a few reasons:

- There are many camping site with the usual stuff **plus** houses, big full houses.
- There are many theme park near (for kids and adults)
- There are many nice and interesting locations to visit and the panorama/environment is really wonderful. And I'm not from the area.

If instead you want to stay on Maggiore or Como lakes it will be way more difficult, for a simple reason: those are areas for a different kind of holidays, mainly old and/or rich people. Or (and I'm not going into details 'cause it would be too long to explain), just because most of those are areas where inhabitants are not interested in tourism or in earning money.

So, to sum it up:

- Best bet is Garda Lake.
- Forget about Como Lake.
- If you want Maggiore Lake, search on Piedmont (Piemonte) side, to the north, after Intra and Pallanza
- There is a camping at Ghirla Lake, it's really nice and is full of strangers, few Italians know it. They are really good (I'm not affiliated in any way, by the way), maybe you could have better luck there. Note, however, Ghirla Lake is not a place for tourism: you'll need to take the car and move around
- Don't forget you are traveling with kids! Yeah, I know you mentioned that, but it seems you are forgetting about it when it comes to "number of people in a place". When it comes to kids, if laws allow for it hosting sites (campings, hotel, etc.) become very very flexible: before giving up a place you like, ask if they can arrange a couple beds more for the kids.

---

Finally, just a personal suggestion: I don't know if your kids fit into it, but camping in a tent is usually waaay more funny. As that area is quite safe, and a camping site being even much more safe, have you thought about renting a bungalow with a bit of a garden and to arrange with the camping owners to have kids staying into tents? (into the garden, I mean)

Comment: Just about every travel agency in The Netherlands refers to "the region of the Italian lakes" when talking about the region surrounding the Garda, Maggiore and Como lakes. Hence my use of the term. :-)

Comment: @FrankKusters I can imagine that, believe me, I was not criticising you. I just find funny the way this definitions pop up from "third parties" like Google, travel agencies, economists...just a week or two ago I discovered that there is an official term that, in short, imply parts of Piemonte and Emilia Romagna are just "an extension of Milano", and I found it amusing given that people outside the proper city of Milano would never define themselves as "from Milano", go figure those from Emilia Romagna :-D